# Sidekiq generating errors on startup : Error fetching message: Invalid argument - connect(2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

Hi sidekiq / ruby / redis experts :

I am not sure if this issue has to do with sidekiq, or redis, or ruby or even rails for that matter.

We are trying to start sidekiq on our dev server (effectively one step away from prod, so we are using rails in prod mode), and the sidekiq log continuously produces the error message :

Error fetching message: Invalid argument - connect(2)

The relevant portion of the log is as follows :

```
# Logfile created on 2014-04-30 15:57:05 -0400 by logger.rb/31641
Running in ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]
See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
{:queues=>["default"], :concurrency=>25, :require=>".", :environment=>"production", :timeout=>8, :error_handlers=>[#<Sidekiq::ExceptionHandler::Logger:0xef8410>], :lifecycle_events=>{:startup=>[], :quiet=>[], :shutdown=>[]}, :strict=>true, :tag=>"price_tracker_rewrite"}
Booting Sidekiq 3.0.0 with redis options {}
Error fetching message: Invalid argument - connect(2)
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:129:in `connect_nonblock'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:129:in `rescue in connect_addrinfo'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:121:in `connect_addrinfo'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:162:in `block in connect'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:160:in `each'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:160:in `each_with_index'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:160:in `connect'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:211:in `connect'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:285:in `establish_connection'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:79:in `block in connect'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:257:in `with_reconnect'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:78:in `connect'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:240:in `with_socket_timeout'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:178:in `call_with_timeout'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis.rb:1038:in `block in _bpop'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis.rb:37:in `block in synchronize'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis.rb:37:in `synchronize'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis.rb:1035:in `_bpop'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis.rb:1080:in `brpop'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:101:in `block in retrieve_work'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/connection_pool-2.0.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:58:in `with'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq.rb:69:in `redis'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:101:in `retrieve_work'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:36:in `block in fetch'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:15:in `watchdog'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:32:in `fetch'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25:in `public_send'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25:in `dispatch'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:122:in `dispatch'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:322:in `block in handle_message'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:416:in `block in task'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:55:in `block in initialize'
E:/Rewrite/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:13:in `block in create'
```

My colleagues & I really have nowhere to go with this, and google has not been of any help.  Thanks for helping!

UPDATE : I am executing sidekiq with the following line : "sidekiq -e production", since this is essentially the mirror of our prod.  I also do not have a sidekiq config file (sidekiq.yml), maybe I need to have one?  Really not sure, but it worked for us without a hitch during testing.  We are also executing sidekiq in Windows environment, in case that matters.

Comment: can you provide your sidekiq config, and your launch line (e.g. `bundle exec sidekiq -e ...`)

Comment: nothing come to mind with your updated info, however since this is a redis connection issue, this could stem from your sidekiq.rb and redis.rb initializers. I could provide some suggestions next, but woudl be good to see these files first.

Comment: @blotto there are no sidekiq.rb nor redis.rb custom initializers at all.  We just start the redis server we have installed (as a service), and just run sidekiq with the command I noted above (out of the box, if you will).  Everything worked perfectly fine on our test environment, and now it gives this error on dev/prod.

Comment: I recommend trying with some initializers. it wont hurt, and may ensure you have more visible control on your configuration in any env.  I'll add some recommendations in an answer to start

Answer (score 0):

firstly  setup some initializers, try these out ( note Heroku ENV var can be replaced with something else)

config/redis.rb

```
 module MyApp
   class << self
     def redis
       @redis ||= Redis.new(url: (ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'] || 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'))
     end

     def sidekiq?
      begin
        redis_info = Sidekiq.redis { |conn| conn.info }
        true
      rescue
         false
       end

      end
   end
 end
```

config/sidekiq.rb

```
 Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
   Rails.logger = Sidekiq::Logging.logger
   config.redis = { :url => MyApp.redis[:url], :namespace => 'sidekiq', :size => 5 }
 end

 Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
   config.redis = { :url => MyApp.redis[:url], :namespace => 'sidekiq', :size => 1 }
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a more fundamental Ruby/windows issue.  Upgrade your MRI version if possible, or give JRuby a shot.